# PowerApps Canvas App Custom Form Design Issue

Tags: office365, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I have created a custom form in the Canvas App.

There is 1 field that is shown/hidden based on another field value.

When the field is hidden it requires a blank space between two fields.

Is there any alternative to remove that blank space while the field is hidden?

Please refer to the below screenshots for a better understanding.

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I have created the PowerBI report using the SharePoint list. I have imported that PowerBI report under my PowerApps.. I have added 1 new item to the SharePoint list but the PowerBI report is not refreshed after adding the new item. Can anyone help me with the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried manually updating the Y value of the lower dropdown based on the above textbox's visible, i'm thinking something along the lines of if the textbox is visible use whatever it has in there already for its Y value (assuming a hard coded number, i've called it gblCurrentY), however if the textbox is not visible move to where the textbox is.

```
If(CDPartnerTextBox.Visible,gblCurrentY,CDPartnerTextBox.Y)
```